# Flask: Apache Httpd font end and websocket support

Tags: python, apache, nginx, flask

I am developing an application where I am using a flask container with websocket support for streaming data to the server. I am using https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sockets for this purpose. I use gunicorn to start the server and all is good.

My question is can I deploy a production server using Apache httpd? I have seen numerous posts that suggest using Nginx as the web server front end. I want a cross platform (windows and linux) solution. However, it appears nginx only has an experimental windows port (for windows 7).  On the other hand, Apache httpd has a stable windows port so if possible I want to go that route. Has anybody successfully deployed Flask websockets with Apache httpd and if so I would love to get some pointers to how to go about doing so. If this is not possible or does not work well, I would appreciate some advice to that effect as well.

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Regards,

Ranga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the current time, it will not be very easy to make such an application cross-platform.

Apache [supports proxying to a web-socket-enabled server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html), but it only runs in POSIX-compliant environments.  (Apache's [evented multi-process module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/event.html) also only runs on systems with Unix-like `{k,e}poll` support).

IIS 8, on the other hand, [ships with support for WebSockets](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support) and is Windows-native.  However, getting Python + IIS running together is either [ridiculously complex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iiswsgi) or else relies on [horrendously out-of-date software](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyisapie/).

Gunicorn [will support Windows in R-20](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/524); which will be released on a yet-to-be-named-date. Once that is released you should be able to run Gunicorn as a Windows Service.

Comment: Thank you for a comprehensive answer. Do you have any configuration tips for how to enable web socket support for Apache running as a front end for flask?

Comment: [Wfastcgi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wfastcgi) seems to be the best option for using Python + IIS, I'm not so sure about fastcgi + websockets though, I wouldn't know if and how this work.